# Hip flexor pain in eccentric when powerlifting

Tags: powerlifting

I seem to struggle quite a lot when I near the top when I eccentric in a squat or a deadlift. What could be some possible solutions to this?

Comment: Diagnosing pain is not what we do here. Consult a doctor or certified trainer.

Comment: Also, what does "near the top when I eccentric" even mean? The very start of a squat and when you begin to lower a deadlift?

Comment: Seconds before I lift the barbell up to maximum heigt in deadlift, and also seconds before I raise the squat to normal height in squat @DavidScarlett

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller that is concentric then, not eccentric. Eccentric is when the weight is being lowered.

Comment: To expand on the comment of @DavidScarlett, concentric and eccentric refers to the muscles working, not the body position. When muscles shorten while actively contracting (muscle force > external force), they work concentricly. When they are getting longer while contracting (muscle force < external force), they work eccentricly. As it is your quads and glutes doing (most of) the "moving" work and they shorten on the way up in deadlifts and squats, that's concentric.